# Using a factory with $http promise returns empty object

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous, factory

I have this simple factory that fetches a data file and saves it to service.data:

```
angular.module("tiki").factory("editTiki", ["$http", function($http){

    var service = {}
    service.data = {}

    service.getTikis = function(){

        $http.get("data/tikis.json").success(function(tikis){

            console.log(tikis)
            service.data = tikis

        })

    }

    return service



}])
```

Then, in the controller i assign it to the $scope. This is first empty ofcourse but when the $http resolves it should update my factory and in turn update the service.data object with the returned data.

```
angular.module('tiki').controller("tiki.controller.settings.edit", ["$scope", "editTiki", function($scope, editTiki){


    //should return the tikis
    $scope.preview = editTiki.data

    editTiki.getTikis()


    $scope.showEditTikiObject = function(){

        console.log($scope.preview)

    }

}])
```

However, i have this function to test the contents of the data and it returns an empty object. Why is that?

Comment: Take a look at this. http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning `service.data = tikis` after assigning it to `$scope.preview`.

You should do probably something with the promise.

```
angular.module("tiki").factory("editTiki", ["$http", function($http){
    var service = {};
    service.data = {};

    service.getTikis = function(){
        return $http.get("data/tikis.json").success(function(tikis){
            console.log(tikis)
            service.data = tikis;

            return service.data;
        })
    };

    return service;
}]);

angular.module('tiki').controller("tiki.controller.settings.edit", ["$scope", "editTiki", function($scope, editTiki){
    editTiki.getTikis()
    .then(function () {
        $scope.preview = editTiki.data;
    });

    $scope.showEditTikiObject = function(){
        console.log($scope.preview);
    };
}])
```

Comment: Yes i don't want to manage the data inside the controller, i want to manage it in the service where it should be. I'm following this article but it's not working for me: http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/

Comment: do u NEED to cache tikis in the service? if not, id get rid of the service.data object entirely and just return the response in the promise which can then be handled via ```then(function (response) { $scope.preview = response.data; });```

Comment: Yes, i need to cache the tikis in the service. I want to factor out the data model in the controller, it should stay in the service.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following. So here I am not injecting the scope object into the factory, but setting the **$scope** in the controller itself using the concept of **promise** returned by **$http** service. Hope this helps.

```
(function () {
    getDataFactory = function ($http)
    {
        return {
            callWebApi: function (reqData)
            {
                var dataTemp = {
                    Page: 1, Take: 10,
                    PropName: 'Id', SortOrder: 'Asc'
                };

                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat',
                    params: dataTemp, // Parameters to pass to external service
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/Json' }
                })                
            }
        }
    }
    patientCategoryController = function ($scope, getDataFactory) {
        alert('Hare');
        var promise = getDataFactory.callWebApi('someDataToPass');
        promise.then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                // Set this response data to scope to use it in UI
                $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data.Collection;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert('Some problem while fetching data!!');
            });
    }
    patientCategoryController.$inject = ['$scope', 'getDataFactory'];
    getDataFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
    angular.module('demoApp', []);
    angular.module('demoApp').controller('patientCategoryController', patientCategoryController);
    angular.module('demoApp').factory('getDataFactory', getDataFactory);    
}());
```